# how to replace json values from "null" to null in jmeter request with parameters?

Tags: java, json, performance, jmeter, load-testing

i am working on a jmeter script as below, i am reading from a old database and passing it to this below script

jmeter script  in the Http Request Body Data

```
  "ID": ${ID}
  "ProductName": "${ProductName}"
  "Name" : "${Name}"
  "NoOfdays": ${Numberofdays}
```

like this up to 300 more parameters

Request
Record # 1

"ID": 1
  "ProductName": "Pixel"
  "Name" : "abcd"
"NoOfdays": 10
  ... up to 300 parameters

Record # 2

"ID": 1
  "ProductName": "null"
  "Name" : "null"
 "NoOfdays": 0
  ... up to 300 parameters

My ESB server throws an error when i send "null" it expects a null with out quotes, how do i replace this values in bulk than using by parameter wise which is a time consuming.

Comment: How do you parse the JSON? Please show a [mcve] which recreates the error.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes from values in Body:

```
  "ProductName": ${ProductName}
  "Name" : ${Name}
```

Add a JSR223 PreProcessor to the request which add quotes if value is not null

```
if (vars.get("ProductName") != null) {
        vars.put("ProductName", "\"" + vars.get("ProductName")  + "\"")
}
if (vars.get("Name") != null) {
        vars.put("Name", "\"" + vars.get("Name")  + "\"")
}
```

In case the value is "null" you can handle it as:

```
if (!"null".equals(vars.get("ProductName") )) {
        vars.put("ProductName", "\"" + vars.get("ProductName")  + "\"")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I have around 300+ parameters with Integer, Digital and String. I need to get rid of String values with "null" to null, for each parameter if we have to write it will take lot of time. Can it be more generic to change values in a loop.

Comment: Just enter names to a list and add a loop through list

Comment: log.info("Before ProductName:" + vars.get("ProductName"));

if (vars.get("ProductName") != null ) 
{
        vars.put("ProductName", "\""  + vars.get("ProductName")  + "\"");
}

log.info("After ProductName:" + vars.get("ProductName"));

--log message --

2018-02-12 14:30:01,355 INFO o.a.j.m.JSR223PreProcessor: Before beginningReferenceMarkerNumber:null
2018-02-12 14:30:01,357 INFO o.a.j.m.JSR223PreProcessor: After beginningReferenceMarkerNumber:"null"

Comment: Add to my answer handle "null"